# How to iterate over a list and a list of Daraframe at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of data frames that I want to assign a suffix to their columns.

```
# read text files 
df_morning = pd.read_csv("df1.txt", sep="\t", error_bad_lines=False, index_col =None)
df_afternoon = pd.read_csv("df2.txt", sep="\t", error_bad_lines=False, index_col =None)
df_night = pd.read_csv("df3.txt", sep="\t", error_bad_lines=False, index_col =None)

#list of data frames
scenarios =[df_morning,df_afternoon,df_night]

#list 
names = ['_morning','_afternoon','_night']

#add suffix 
for name,scenario in zip(names,scenarios):
    scenario.add_suffix("{}".format(name)).rename(columns={"personId{}".format(name): "personId"}, inplace = True)
    #scenario.reset_index(inplace = True)


df_morning.head()
```

the result is the same. so nothing has been changed in the name of columns.
How I can change the name of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrame.add_suffix` does not change things `in-place` but returns a new dataframe as shown in the documentation, assign it to a variable to see change

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html

```
df_morning = pd.read_csv("df1.txt", sep="\t", error_bad_lines=False, index_col =None)
df_afternoon = pd.read_csv("df2.txt", sep="\t", error_bad_lines=False, index_col =None)
df_night = pd.read_csv("df3.txt", sep="\t", error_bad_lines=False, index_col =None)

#list of data frames
scenarios =[df_morning,df_afternoon,df_night]

#list 
names = ['_morning','_afternoon','_night']

#add suffix 
new_scenarios = []
for name,scenario in zip(names,scenarios):
    new_scenario = scenario.add_suffix("{}".format(name)).rename(columns={"personId{}".format(name): "personId"}, inplace = True)
    #scenario.reset_index(inplace = True)
    new_scenarios.append(new_scenario)


new_scenarios[0].head()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is reason `add_suffix` not working inplace, so need:

```
for i, (name,scenario) in enumerate(zip(names,scenarios)):
    scenarios[i] = (scenario.add_suffix("{}".format(name))
                            .rename(columns={"personId{}".format(name): "personId"}))
```